# DEM of Mars surface with .img/.lbl files

Tags: gazebo-11, gazebo-all-versions

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi there,

I have followed the proposed tutorial about DEM (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=dem&cat=build_world) and I successfully obtained a DEM of the vulcain: the file `mtsthelens_129.dem` called by `volcano.world` is of type `.dem`, and the simulation works fine.

Now I am trying to create a DEM of a portion of Mars surface, so
I downloaded a `.img` file containing the raster data of Mars surface (this is the link: http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/mgs/mgs-m-mola-5-megdr-l3-v1/mgsl_300x/meg004/megt90n000cb.img)

Note that there is an associated `.lbl` file at this link http://pds-geosciences.wustl.edu/mgs/mgs-m-mola-5-megdr-l3-v1/mgsl_300x/meg004/megt90n000cb.lbl, but I don't know how to use it.

Then I created a `.world` file, but when I run the simulation the following error occurs:

```
ERROR 4: `/usr/share/gazebo-11/media/dem/megt90n000cd.img' not recognized as a supported file format. Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato)
```

However, I believe that Gazebo can realize DEM models using a file whose format is not necessarily `.dem`, according to what is said in the tutorial:

**Currently, Gazebo only supports raster data in the supported formats available in GDAL**

These formats are listed  in this page: https://gdal.org/. In particular I am interested in the **PDS – Planetary Data System v3**; about PDS files, in the GDAL web page can be found that:

**PDS files often have the extension .img, sometimes with an associated .lbl (label) file. When a .lbl file exists it should be used as the dataset name rather than the .img file**

but I don't know what does it mean.

My question is: can I use files whose format is different from `.dem` in order to create a DEM? Can I convert a `.img` file containing raster data in a `.dem` one?

Could anyone please help me? Thanks a lot in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/24904/dem-of-mars-surface-with-.img/.lbl-files/) by [Simone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24349/simone/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 30 on 2020-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When there are both a `.lbl` file and an associated `.img` file, the `.world` file should load the `.lbl` file rather than the `.img` one. In fact, in some way the `.lbl` file takes automatically the data contained in the `.img` one.

However, both files should be saved in the same directory.

Note that with the command `gdal_translate` the `.lbl` file can be converted in a `.dem` or `.tif` one.

---

Originally posted by [Simone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/24349/simone/) with karma: 30 on 2020-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0